# Writing Powershell Help Files

Tags: c#, powershell, module

I'm trying to write some help files for a bunch of PowerShell modules that I've written in C#. I've struggled to find anything as far as doing so, and have tried using this help editor

https://pscmdlethelpeditor.codeplex.com/

but I'm trying to work out some bugs with the author. Long story short it says it uses powershell 2.0 and it's trying to use 3.0.

Back on topic, I need a solid way to know how to write help files for my c# powershell modules. I've tried following MSDN

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525433(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

but let's be honest, it's microsoft help, and this is less than helpful.

Comment: Take a look at [Helps](https://github.com/nightroman/Helps). I created it for myself and use for several years in several projects. It is unusual perhaps but it is really useful. And simple, actually.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin your comment looks like an answer to me...

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, the Help documents on MSDN leaves a lot to your imagination. If you like learning by example, you could have a look at the help files for the existing PowerShell modules:

```
$fs = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules -Recurse 
$fs |Where {$_.Name -like "*dll-Help.xml"} |Select FullName
```

It'll give you a much better idea about how Microsoft themselves use this format